# How do I grab value from dictionary so it can work with while loop?

Tags: python

This is what I tried so far. I know it may be basic but I cant figure out how I can make this work. If anyone understands please help me.

```
sterling = { "name": "Hifenn Sterling", "age": 23, "ethnicity": "Haitian American"}

guess= ""


while guess != (sterling["age"]):
guess = input("How old do you think Sterling is?: ")

print ("answer")
```

Comment: You just need to convert the input to an integer: `guess = int(input("How old..."))`

Comment: You also need to indent the `guess =` line.

Comment: Integer and string are two data types and are not equal even if they hold the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that works on Python 3.8+ using the walrus `:=` operator:

```py
sterling = {"name": "Hifenn Sterling", "age": 23, "ethnicity": "Haitian American"}

age = sterling['age']

while guess := int(input("How old do you think Sterling is?: ")) != age:
    print("answer")
```